# CloudBees Jenkins Pipeline Job input Param not accessible in 'Pipeline script from SCM' section

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, cloudbees

I've defined input Jenkins variable `BRANCH` as below
[image]

I tried to access it in `'Pipeline script from SCM'` but no luck. `BRANCH` value never evaluate?
I used below syntaxes.

1. `${BRANCH}`
2. `${params.BRANCH}`
3. `${env.BRANCH}`
4. `BRANCH`
5. `env.BRANCH`

[image]

None of this evaluate to actual value, how can I get value that user specified?

```
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command 
"git fetch --tags --force --progress --prune -- origin
+refs/heads/env.BRANCH:refs/remotes/origin/env.BRANCH"
returned status code 128:
```

Comment: `BRANCH` name might be reserved. Try `CODE_BRANCH` or something, and evaluate it with `"${params.CODE_BRANCH}"`

Comment: nope. There is no restriction when you do `"${params.SOME_VALUE}"`

Comment: @SwapnilKotwal just tested `${BRANCH}` and it seems to work

Comment: @NoamHelmer Yes it works for the open sources installed Jenkins but I'm using enterprise CloudBees and no luck with `${BRANCH}` OR `${params.BRANCH}` OR `${env.BRANCH}` OR `BRANCH` OR `env.BRANCH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found that I've checked `Lightweight checkout` option and that's why it wasn't resolving this input param values.

I've uncheck `Lightweight checkout` option and `${BRANCH}` is resolving it's value correctly